# submodule of a semisimple module has complement

Tags: modules, semi-simple-rings

I want to prove that a submodule of a semisimple module admits a complement.
That is, if S $\subset$ M, then there exists T $\subset$ M, such that
M = S $\bigoplus$ T.
One supposes that M = $\bigoplus$ Mi, with Mi simple submodules.
Then one may consider those i such that Mi $\cap$ S = {0},say i$\in$ J and take as T := $\bigoplus$Mi, i $\in$J. 
Since S = $\bigoplus$ (S $\cap$Mi), i $\notin$ J,(since for i $\in$ J, S $\cap$ Mi = {0} then clearly M = S $\bigoplus$ T.

Comment: And S $\cap$Mi = Mi, for i $\notin$ J.

Comment: I have just found this post, my answer seems tooshort and easy, where is the mistake, if so?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2049349/m-is-semisimple-if-and-only-if-every-submodule-is-a-direct-summand?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Either $S$ contains $M_i$ completely or $S \cap M_i=\{0\}$ for all $i$. What happens if $S \neq \sum_{j \in J} M_j$ where $J \subseteq I$ and $M_j \in S$ for all $j \in J$.